# Exiting due to GUEST_MOUNT_CONFLICT : While starting minikube

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to use `kubernetes` for local deployment using `minikube`, I want to mount a share a directory between host machine and pods. For this, I am trying to mount directory to `minikube`. But I already had minikube running on which few deployments were running. I deleted them. But every time I restart minikube with mount I get following error

```
$ minikube start --mount-string="/var/log:/log" --mount
* minikube v1.14.2 on Ubuntu 18.04
* Using the docker driver based on existing profile
* Starting control plane node minikube in cluster minikube
* Restarting existing docker container for "minikube" ...

X Exiting due to GUEST_MOUNT_CONFLICT: Sorry, docker does not allow mounts to be changed after container creation (previous mount: '', new mount: '/var/log:/log)'
```

Output for kubectl get all is

```
kubectl get all
NAME                 TYPE        CLUSTER-IP   EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)   AGE
service/kubernetes   ClusterIP   10.96.0.1    <none>        443/TCP   2s
```

What am I doing wrong here. I need to mount `/var/log:/log` in my pods just like docker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you see happens when you try to change the mount configuration on an existing cluster when using Docker. Docker doesn't allow changing of volumes after the container has been created and thus you cannot change the `mount-string` on `minikube start` after the cluster has already been created. More info and source for this behavior can be found [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/8159) and [here](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/pull/9172).

Answer (score 6):

You will have to delete the minikube container first using `minikube delete` , after that recreate the container with the new mount path `minikube start --mount-string="/var/log:/log" --mount`
Check this Github [Issue](https://github.com/kubernetes/minikube/issues/11084) for more details

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
$ minikube mount /Users/user/dir:/opt/dir
$ minikube ssh
$ ls /opt/dir  # this should be mounted within minikube VM
```

and start minikube initially without any flags

```
$ minikube start
```