# OpenEBS ndm pod stuck in on Minikube: MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "udev" : hostPath type check failed: /run/udev is not a directory

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, udev, openebs

I am trying to run OpenEBS on Minikube v1.29.0 with --driver=docker and --kubernetes-version=v1.23.12. I have installed OpenEBS using the following command:

```
kubectl apply -f https://openebs.github.io/charts/openebs-operator.yaml
```

However, the openebs-ndm pod is stuck in ContainerCreating status.

When I run `kubectl describe pod openebs-ndm-bbj6s -n openebs`, I get the following error message:

```
Events:
  Type     Reason       Age                From               Message
  ----     ------       ----               ----               -------
  Normal   Scheduled    51s                default-scheduler  Successfully assigned openebs/openebs-ndm-bbj6s to minikube
  Warning  FailedMount  19s (x7 over 51s)  kubelet            MountVolume.SetUp failed for volume "udev" : hostPath type check failed: /run/udev is not a directory
```

I have tried installing udev as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70507005/etc-udev-directory-not-present-in-docker-container) on my host but it didn't work. Any ideas on how to solve this issue?

Comment: Can you check this `/run/udev` directory is available on your machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `/run/udev` is available in a local machine and not present in minkube cluster, then try to mount that folder into minkube cluster by using the `minkube mount` command, because to run the OpenEBS properly it required access to `/run/udev`.

```
#Syntax of minkube mount
$ minikube start --mount-string="source_path:destination_path" --mount

#In your case try something like this
$ minikube start --mount-string="/run/udev:/run/udev" --mount
```

This will mount the `/run/udev` to the minkube cluster. Now redeploy the pods and monitor the volume mount of the pod.

Have a glance at a similar error reference in [github issues](https://github.com/openebs/openebs/issues/3489).

Comment: When I run this, I get the following error: ```Exiting due to GUEST_MOUNT_CONFLICT: Sorry, docker does not allow mounts to be changed after container creation (previous mount: '', new mount: '/run/udev:/run/udev)'```.
I also tried running ```minikube mount "/run/udev:/run/udev"``` which needs the process to stay alive but it didn't work as well

Comment: As suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64969502/exiting-due-to-guest-mount-conflict-while-starting-minikube) can you try deleting the minikube container first. Because docker doesn't allow to change the volume after the container creation is done. So try deleting the minikube container with `minikube delete` and mount.